# SQL Azure doesn't support SqlCacheDependency? is there any replacement for that

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database

How can I implement the SQL caching dependency while SQL Azure doesn't support SqlCacheDependency.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN article [Caching in ASP.NET with the SqlCacheDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) describes how `SqlCacheDependency` is implemented.
Starting with SQL Server 2005, the `SqlCacheDependency` class is able to take advantage of SQL Server Service Broker and Query Notifications.
Since SQL Server Service Broker was introduced with SQL Server 2005, the implementation of `SqlCacheDependency` for earlier versions of SQL Server uses a different technique: polling.

SQL Azure currently does not support SQL Server Service Broker, but it does support polling.
Thus, either setup `SqlCacheDependency` using the polling mechanism or create your own custom `CacheDependency`.

Comment: thanks for posting this details, can you provide a link for SqlCacheDependency  using the polling mechanism. I searched in the web, but nothing found! can you help here ?