# Statement 'CREATE QUEUE' is not supported in azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to execute this command on Windows Azure to be able to use [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
USING [mytable]
CREATE QUEUE NewsAddedQueue;
CREATE SERVICE NewsAddedService ON QUEUE NewsAddedQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

but it retuns this error:

```
Statement 'CREATE QUEUE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Is there any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Broker for SQL Server is not supported in SQL Azure, and queues in SQL Server are a feature of Service Broker.

There is however a feature request that you can vote for on UserVoice: [Enable SQL Service Broker in SQL Azure](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure%20Enable%20SQL%20Service%20Broker%20in%20SQL%20Azure)

Comment: ops, then what developers do to work with SqlCacheDependency ??

Comment: I think you can still work with SqlCacheDependency, but you have to initialize it to only use the pre-Service Broker functionality. More information in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249375/sql-azure-doesnt-support-sqlcachedependency-is-there-any-replacement-for-that

Comment: thanks for posting this details, can you provide a link for SqlCacheDependency using the polling mechanism. I searched in the web, but nothing found! can you help me here ?

Comment: thanks, i found a good blog talking about  "SqlCacheDependency via polling" . it may help someone http://kabsang.com/2012/10/14/sqlcachedependency-via-polling/