# Cache "dictionary-like" DB entities in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, azure-sql-database

I have asp.net mvc5 project hosted in Azure that is using SQL Azure for data persistence. Some tables in my database are like dictionaries, they are referenced by lots of tables, and very rarely changed. One example of such table can be Client app type: Windows, Windows Phone, Android, etc.

But there are much more DB insert operations that inserts data into tables that have foreign references to those dict tables.
I want to optimize and do not make SQL query to dictionary table to get id of some entity every time I want to insert (this is not premature optimization, Azure may change some money per number of queries).

What is good approach to achieve that? Currently I have DAO-like entity managers with static field that gets populated when object is constructed or explicitly called Refresh() (when dictionary data is updated via my asp.net mvc app). Each Manager caches entities from its own table. 
It is like poor man's caching. I wonder is there a better way to do that? Are there any patterns/libraries/techniques to cache "dictionary-like" data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [System.Web.Caching.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It provides a good caching framework, and allows for a variety of cache expiration policies.

You control caching with a [CacheDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be as simple as a time duration until the cache must be refreshed, or as complex as a [SqlCacheDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency(v=vs.110).aspx) that automatically refreshes the cache when the underlying SQL table changes (more complicated to setup, but more efficient as it avoids unnecessary refreshes for slowly-changing tables, and avoids the cache being out-of-sync when the table does change).

Comment: It seems you can configure SqlCacheDependency to use polling rather than change notifications.  Not tried it myself.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111264/141172

Comment: SqlCacheDependency takes advantage of SQL Server Service Broker and Query Notifications. I don't believe these are supported in Azure based on what I'm reading.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras: Did you have a look at the answer I linked above, and the MSDN article that it links to?

Comment: Just read it. No Service Broker, but it does support polling with the SqlCacheDependancy. Not a fan of this approach, but it should work.

Comment: Bear in mind that Azure websites are periodically unavailable for maintenance etc, and Microsoft recommend you run at least 2 instances; in fact their SLA does not apply if you only run one. When you use System.Web.Caching.Cache, it runs in local instance memory; therefore the cache can be out of synch on more than one instance. You mention that the data changes rarely, and depending on how important the application is, you might not need an uptime guarantee. But, best to be aware that the Redis solution proposed here is designed for scenarios where you will have more than one web instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are hosting your application in Azure and using SQL Azure, then why not use Microsoft Azure Redis Cache. Redis is an advanced key-value cache and store.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/

How to use it:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/

Comment: If you ever want to move away from Azure, you'll either need to setup your own Redis (if your new provider doesn't offer a comparable service), or rewrite the caching code.  Doesn't mean it's a bad choice, but weigh those factors.

Comment: Redis is a first in class piece of software. So even if you move away from Azure, I doubt you'd drop Redis from your architecture. That being said, setting up a Redis server isn't overly complicated especially since there is a Windows port of it along with solid Redis clients including one from stackexchange. I've used the Service Stack client - worked well.

Comment: Redis server is another piece of the architecture that needs to be installed, patched, operated and represents an additional point of failure.  It is more complex than System.Web.Caching.Cache.  It can be a fine choice but that extra complexity should not be ignored.

Comment: It is more complex, but the more robust choice. Given his app is already on Azure and using existing services. Why not use it? If he wasn't using Azure, then I think other caching options would be ok. Though, I'd still suggest Redis :)

Comment: Because I have been through many efforts to migrate code between platforms.  My experience says to only lock into a particular platform when the benefits outweigh potential future migration cost.  I cannot judge for the OP whether or not that is the case.